# jQuery data tables plugin nested data tables' sub data table don't have functionality

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$query= $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM analytics');
$query->execute();
$getData= $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$dataList = array();

foreach ($getData as $sorgu) {
  $number = $sorgu->numbers;

  if (!array_key_exists($number, $dataList)) {
    $dataList[$number] = array();
  }

  array_push($dataList[$number], array(
    'campaign' => $sorgu->campaign,
    'page' => $sorgu->page,
    'timePage' => $sorgu->timePage,
    'date' => $sorgu->date,
    'timestamp' => $sorgu->timestamp
  ));
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 30px;
      color: #333;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    table.dataTable>tbody>tr.child ul.dtr-details {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DATA GÖSTER</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>NUMBER</th>
          <th>CAMPAIGN</th>
          <th class="none">PAGES</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($dataList as $number => $data) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="details-control"></td>
            <td><?= $number ?></td>
            <td><?= 'CAMPAIGN' ?></td>
            <td>
              <table id="table-<?= $number ?>" class="display nowrap sub_table" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>CAMPAIGN</th>
                    <th>PAGE</th>
                    <th>TIME PAGE</th>
                    <th>DATE</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach ($data as $page) : ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?= $page['campaign'] ?></td>
                      <td><?= $page['page'] ?></td>
                      <td><?= $page['timePage'] ?></td>
                      <td><?= date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($page['date'])) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    const tableList = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
      let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        stateSave: true
      });

      tableList.push(table);
    });

    $('.sub_table').each(function(index, tableElement) {
      let table = $(`#${tableElement.id}`).DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        stateSave: true
      });

      tableList.push(table);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created this data table with nested data tables using data acquired from MySQL database using PHP PDO. Data acquired fits well on the tables, there's no empty row/column in tables. Main data table has functionality to search, filter, sort rows. But the nested/inner data tables don't have this functionality. I can't spot what causes this to happen.

Comment: Look here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42045/nested-tables#Comment_109541

Comment: @Grumpy I checked all the comments but I think you were referencinh a modal/editor solution for my case. I don't really want to open a modal or editor to show the sub data table. I just want to show sub data table and get it working I mean pagination, search etc.